# External SSD with Ubuntu not regonized by HP Boot system

Tags: windows-10, hp-pavilion

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an external Samsung SSD 1TB. It has one partition with 50gb and one with 950 GB. The 50GB is primary and Ubuntu is installed on the 50 GB partition which was created within the installation. I installed it on my Windows 10 HP 15-cs3722nd laptop but now it doesn't regonize the external SSD with Ubuntu on it. Not in the UEFI and not in if I brake the startup and press F9 (Boot options). I changed the boot to "Legacy mode" and it shows the hard drive but not the start up partition. It seems like it doesn't see the boot start-up from Ubuntu. It skips the boot and goes to Windows 10, even if I force it to boot from the external hard drive. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I would like to use Ubuntu on an external drive and not as dual boot on my laptop.

I used a USB as the installation drive (a live boot) and installed it on the external hard drive with no problems. The booting is the problem. I performed the same on an laptop with Windows 7 and that worked fine, including the booting.

Also an other thing (this question does not have priority): how do I delete in the UEFI boot partition an Ubuntu start up partition? I don't know how it get there since I looked carefully on which hard drive I installed Ubuntu. It has no Ubuntu installed on it. This made me very confused.

Comment: Can I confirm the situation? You installed Ubuntu on an external SSD using Computer A, and are trying to boot it on Computer B? Or are you trying to boot Ubuntu from the same HP where you performed the installation?

Comment: I am trying to boot it on the same HP laptop where I performed the installation, as you say, computer A. I used a USB as the installation drive (a live boot) and installed it on the external hard drive with no problems. The booting is the problem. I performed the same on an laptop with windows 7 and that worked fine, including the booting

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub to internal drive's ESP. That will work only if you always boot from same system you installed from. You need an ESP on external drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu If directly booting external drive then it is a drive entry using /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079 Other work arounds:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Thnx I'm gonna check this out!